# How can I loop thorugh untill I get the element to click with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer

I have tried this code

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
// const select = require ('puppeteer-select');

let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/gaming/gaming-accessories/gaming-headsets/logitech-g635-7-1-gaming-headset-black-10191019-pdt.html', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});
  


    // // add to cart
    const [button1] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Accept All Cookies')]");
    if (button1) {
        await button1.click();
        const [button2] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Add to basket')]");
        if (button2) {
            await button2.click();
            console.log('Added to cart');
        } else {
            console.log("NO button found");
        }
    } else {
        console.log("NO button found");
    }
    // browser.close();

};

scrape()
```

I have tried with different product which is in stock, I can click the button but the button doesn't fire any event.

the basic Idea is to create a bot, witch is scans my given url and when product back in stock on e-shop is should notify me.

e.g url: https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/gaming/gaming-accessories/gaming-headsets/logitech-g-pro-x-7-1-gaming-headset-black-10195740-pdt.html

bot on my pc scan this is url very second, and when it comes in stock bot will ad to cart and notify me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are 2 buttons returned by the `page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Add to basket')]")` and first is hidden. Maybe try:

```js
const [, button2] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Add to basket')]");
```

Comment: Okay I will try that.